# Positioning a component in .jsx-file and not via a .css-file

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, position, css-position

I'm looking for a solution how to position a component in a `.jsx-file` instead of a `.css-file` because I have multiple files of the same component, but each one is responsible for different tasks so I need them in different positions of the page.

I don't want to have multiple copies of the same file with only a minor change of the css class - I would rather like to add changes to the `.jsx-file`, or if you know how to achieve that using a `.css-file`, please let me know.

Example:

I have a 'Fish'-file which gives the basic structure of what the fish will look like.
I have to make multiple fish files(i.e fish.jsx, fish1.jsx, fish2.jsx) because they each use a different css class for their positioning. How can I reduce the amount of Fish.jsx to one either by adding to the original `fish.jsx` or `.css-file` used?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach your problem would be something like this

```
import Fish from './Fish';
import './Fish.css';

// other stuff

const FishContainer => (
  {[...Array(10)].map( (_, i) => <Fish className=`fish-${i}` /> )}
);

export default FishContainer;
```

And in your css file

```
.fish {
  &-1 {}
  &-2 {}
  // etc
}
```